# LDAP Get users from group recursively

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

Helo,

Having this structure in LDAP:

```
- Group1
    - User1
    - User2
- Group2
    - Group1
- Group3
    - Group2
```

I need a PHP function with will give me an array of Users (only users) of a passed group. For example:

```
$array_users = getLdapGroupUsers (Group3)
```

The result should be:

```
$array_users = ['User1','User2']
```

Any help?

I tried with this but there is not any result:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect($ip) or die('Could not connect to LDAP');
ldap_bind($ldap, $basedn, $passwd) or die('Could not bind to LDAP');
$gFilter = '(&(objectClass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=Group3,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=net))';
$gAttr = array('cn');
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $basedn, $gFilter, $gAttr) or exit('Unable to search LDAP server');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Our LDAP server is a Samba 4.1.17 and it has no recursivity feature.
I connected to a different server (Samba 4.7.6) witch has this feature and it works great like this:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect($ip) or die('Could not connect to LDAP');
ldap_bind($ldap, $dn, $passwd) or die('Could not bind to LDAP');
$gFilter = '(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Group3,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=net))';
$gAttr = array('cn');
$result = ldap_search($ldap, $basedn, $gFilter, $gAttr) or exit('Unable to search LDAP server');
$users = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
```